# How can I format a partition as HFS on a PC?

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, hfs

For various unimportant reasons, I want to format a partition using MacOS's native HFS filesystem.

Is there any software that will let me do this on a PC, without connecting the hard drive directly to a Mac?

Answer (score 4):

With [Gparted](http://www.gparted.org), you can format a partition as either `HFS` or `HFS+`.

[image]

Comment: I assume this user is on Windows. You should add in a note that says OP will need to use the gparted live CD.