# How Format a USB as Mac OS x Extended on Windows

Tags: mac, usb, format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I format a partition as HFS on a PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/111065/how-can-i-format-a-partition-as-hfs-on-a-pc)

Is there a piece of software that can help me do this on Windows 7? My overall goal is to create a portable Mac OS X boot from USB, but all the tutorials I've found require me to format my USB as Mac OS X Extended, which requires me being on a Mac. Is there a way around this?

Comment: [HFS Plus is also referred to as Mac OS Extended (or, erroneously, “HFS Extended”), where its predecessor, HFS, is also referred to as Mac OS Standard (or, erroneously, as “HFS Standard”).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus)

Comment: The Wikipedia article indicates another common name is `HFS+`. The [question](http://superuser.com/questions/111065/how-can-i-format-a-partition-as-hfs-on-a-pc) this is marked as a duplicate of *does* give instructions on formatting. That comment with the Wikipedia link is just pointing out `HFS+` means the same thing as `Mac OS Extended`.